# How to pass parameter in rails method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following method that returns true or false:

```
def my_method?
  # do stuff here
end
```

The question is, can I pass parameter with above method? How can I achieve this thanks!

I do like this but it won't work:

```
def my_method?(params)
  # do stuff
end

User.my_method?(params)
```

Comment: try User.new.my_method?(params)

Comment: im assuming my_method? is defined inside User class...

Comment: `def my_method?(params)` this is an instance method and thus must be called on an instance of your User class eg `User.new.my_method?(params)` (as per the other comment). If you want to be able to call it on your User class itself, then you must define it as a class method eg: `def self.my_method?(params)`

Comment: Thanks both of you but I most like the answer of @TarynEast.

Comment: Well... I wrote my answer from bed using the on screen keyboard. So, I like Taryn's answer too :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def my_method?(params)`
```

will create an instance method, which thus must be called on an instance of your `User` class eg

```
User.new.my_method?(params)
```

(as per the other comment)

If you want to be able to call it on your User class itself, then you must define it as a class method eg:

```
def self.my_method?(params)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can make use of params in ruby methods

```
def my_method?(params)
  variable1 = params[:temp1] 
  variable2 = params[:temp2] 
end
```

And here is how you can call it

```
User.my_method?({temp1: 'This is my method etc', temp2: 'Another parameter'})
```